# Make a xls file in a jsp and then send it to the server

Tags: java, jsp, xls

I have an application where the server sends the data to a jsp file which gives the format and style and builds the xls file.
Using:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+ name+ "\"");
```

then is offered to the user to open or save the file as usual.
The problem is that what I want is send that xls file to the server so it can be worked with and saved there.
Is there any way to do it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont save the document when you are on the server side moment, before render into the view?. Then you can decide if the user want to remove just have to tell you to remove the xml that you just create.
If not the only way that I know is if you use JQuery use JQuery file upload http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I need. The problem is that I don't write a real xls file. It's just outputing it as xls and offer promt to the user to save or open it. After more investigation I'm afraid it's not possible to do what I need :( . Thanks anyway